# 'LINQ.SalesTaxRate' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Whenver i used the method Max().it gives me the error at .ToList() that 'LINQ.SalesTaxRate' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'LINQ.SalesTaxRate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

SalesTaxRate is my table name.

```
 private void Button_Click_7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    using (LinqContainer context = new LinqContainer())
                    {
                        var salesTaxRateList = (from c in context.SalesTaxRates
                                                               orderby c.SalesTaxRateID
                                                               select c).Max()
                                                                     .ToList();
                        grid.ItemsSource = salesTaxRateList;


                    }
```

Comment: You are using a GRID to display only one result. Max() will only return one value so a grid is probably not whay you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query can be much more simple

```
var salesTaxRateList =context.SalesTaxRates.Max(c=>c.SalesTaxRateField)
```

Where the SalesTaxRateField is the value you want the Maximum of.

See also my comment: You are using a GRID to display only one result. Max() will only return one value so a grid is probably not whay you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are selecting the maximum SalesTaxRate object (with `Max`) and then trying to turn it into a list.

If all you are trying to retrieve is the maximum TaxRate value, then simply do a `Max()`. `ToList()` is not necessary because you are only trying to retrieve a single item (and not a full list), and `orderby` is not needed either because `Max()` retrieves the maximum element automatically, without needing to sort the list as a whole.

Comment: I just want to find the maximum value from column TaxRate.

Comment: Then you don't need the ToList(). The Max() will return the maximum TaxRate value as a TaxRate object that you can manipulate directly.

Comment: Updated answer. Does that answer your question?